# GRUB shows brief blue screen on startup

Tags: grub2, startup

I want to start up my computer and get to GRUB (it's worked before) but now every time I turn my computer on, GRUB shows as a blank blue screen for about ten seconds, and then automatically boots into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the Grub Application.

---

**Step 1**

In Terminal type in:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Step 2**

Type in:

```
sudo apt-get install grub2
```

If it tells you that 1 item upgraded or installed, your done. Try rebooting and see if it is all fixed.

If, however, it tells you that `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove` it probably will not be!

If it still is't working move on to Step 3.

**Step 3** *Remove Grub 2*

<s>sudo apt-get remove grub2</s>

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install grub2
```

then go to **Step 2**

***Do NOT reboot before you have reinstalled it***

***Please note**: I have not tried this, but it should work OK.*

Comment: Could you explain the -1 please.